# char* conversion and aliasing rules

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

According to strict aliasing rules:

```
struct B { virtual ~B() {} };
struct D : public B { };

D d;
char *c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d);
```

A `char*` to any object of different type is valid. But now the question is, will it point to the same address of &d? what is the guarantee made by C++ Standard that it will return the same address?

Comment: I think your destructor is misnamed

Comment: I don't know the answer.  But, when would this knowledge **ever** be useful in practice?

Comment: Good question. Some casts can actually change the address (e.g. when multiple inheritance is involved). I wonder if that's the case.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same address"? What should be equal to what?

Comment: where is the question ? (the problem that u can't solve)

Comment: @Oli: Lets say writing the struct to a file or how would the conversion will return success if it doesn't point to the same address? E.g. if `struct D` in above example had a member `int x;` then is it guaranteed that `char*` would point to the first byte of x?

Comment: @user1086635: You really don't want to be serializing non-[POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) data-types by simply reinterpreting them as strings of bytes.  For instance, in your case, that virtual function means your class instances will have [vptrs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) in them.  There would be no useful way in which you could deserialize this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`c` and `&d` do indeed have the same value, and if you reinterpret-cast `c` back to a `D*` you get a valid pointer that you may dereference. Furthermore, you can treat `c` as (pointer to the first element of) an opaque array `char[sizeof(D)]` -- this is indeed the main purpose of casting pointers to char pointers: To allow (de)serialization (e.g. `ofile.write(c, sizeof(D));`), although you should generally only do this for primitive types (and arrays thereof), since the binary layout of of compound types is not generally specified in a portable fashion.

As @Oli rightly points out and would like me to reinforce, you should really never serialize compound types as a whole. The result will almost never be deserializable, since the implementation of polymorphic classes and padding between data fields is not specified and not accessible to you.

Note that `reinterpret_cast<char*>(static_cast<B*>(&d))` may be treated as an opaque array `char[sizeof(B)]` by similar reasoning.

Comment: I think perhaps you should make it clearer that serializing/deserializing non-POD classes like this (i.e. ones with vptrs) is a very very bad idea.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Hm, the *objects* don't have any hidden "vptrs"... that's all just in the class implementation. The objects should still have fairly "normal" layout, at least until you get into virtual inheritance... the usual padding problems are a far more immediate reason not to serialise class types in the "naive" way (though then again there may be situations where it's OK, e.g. HPC clusters of identical machines using memory-mapped network I/O...). Buyer beware :-)

Comment: What?  The existence of virtual functions means that the class instances must have a vptr (well, in any typical implementation).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Hm, I might have a wrong idea about this... I always thought there's just one vtable per *class*. All you need is an instance pointer to call member functions, even virtual ones...

Comment: Indeed, the class contains the vtable.  But each instance contains a vptr which points at the vtable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: So these vptrs aren't fixed even if you deploy the same executable on a collection of identical machines?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not; it would certainly be in the realm of implementation-defined/undefined behaviour.  Things like ASLR and relocatable objects would definitely screw things up.

Answer (score 2):

Section 5.2.10, point 7 of the 2003 C++ Standard says:

> A pointer to an object can be explicitly converted to a pointer to an
>   object of different type. Except that converting an rvalue of type
>   “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are
>   object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1) and **back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value**, the result of such a pointer conversion is
>   unspecified.

If by "same address" you mean "original pointer value," then this entry says "yes."

Answer (score 0):

The intent is clear (and not something that needs to be debated):

**`reinterpret_cast` never changes the value of an address**, unless the target type cannot represent all address values (like a small integer type, on a pointer type with intrinsic alignment: f.ex. a pointer that can only represent even addresses, or pointers to object and pointers to functions cannot be mixed...).

The wording of the standard fails to capture that, but that doesn't mean there is a real practical issue here.

```
char *c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d);
```

`c` will point to the first byte of `d`, always.